# Overflow on safari when child element is sticky and parent element is rotated

Tags: html, css, safari, overflow

I have 2 div elements where the parent element is rotated 10degrees and the child element is sticky. In Opera and Chrome there is no overflow and the child stops being sticky at the end of the parent. However in Safari the child element keeps on going and stops after it has overflown, and the more degrees the parent is rotated, the more the overflow. i have tried setting different overflow properties but that just stops everything from moving.
I have also added an image to show the exact issue.

[image: Overflow on Safari]

```css
.big-div {
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  width: 100%;
}

.slash-div {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 600px;
  width: 80%;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}

.sub-div {
  background-color: coral;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 200px;">
  <div class="slash-div">

    <div class="sub-div">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="big-div"></div>
```

Comment: I've made lots of tests, and I don't have any clue... Dirty fix would be to add an `:after` pseudo element on your `.slash-div` and place id below your element, to hide the overflow of your sticky element, but not that nice...